# Timeouts in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, timeout

I have an issue.  Earlier I thought it was my code, but after extensive testing, I have found it is not the code.  I am running GoDaddy Managed Wordpress.  I have a script that takes a long time to run because it has extensive use of curl.  The big problem is once it gets to 60 seconds or so, the entire page is refreshed and now the script is running twice.  It continues this way until I manage to end the madness.  I have tried to set the max execution time in the htaccess file.  No help.  I have tried to change Google Chrome auto reload from offline settings, no help.  I tried running the page from Firefox, no help.  Right now, I am just running a test using nothing by sleep commands to simulate the long script times so I know it is not the code.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the standard php timeout. That is documented. Since it appears you are using some sort of "wordpress service" I suggest you address the service provider support, since (probably) only they can rasie time limits. Note however that doing so is a security issue, so they might refuse to. You should think of altering your strategy.

Comment: So the standard php timeout reloads the page automatically?  Through testing I have found it reloads all the scripts.  I was under the impression the php timeout would stop script processing.  It is reloading the script into infinitiy unless I hit stop in the browser.

Comment: Ok, I have spoken with GoDaddy.  They have no timeouts except what is built in to PHP.  I have changed these max_execution_time and max_input_time to 600 seconds just in case.  I have verified these settings with ini_get.  It is still doing the same thing at roughly 60 seconds.  I also tried with FireFox disabling the timeout function in the browser.  Still the same problem.

Comment: Very strange. Some things sound fishy here. But anyway: I'd say the next step is to open your browsers development console and check the networking tag in there. Monitor the requests, especially the results of the requests.

Comment: It also might be of interest for you to post your systems URL so that others can take a look at it.

Comment: I still have not figured it out, but have come up with a workaround I will post as an answer tonight.  I will also post the test code so you guys can play around with the problem for whoever is curious.